# XML to Fixed Length File Using XSLT (Complex Position Logic)

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

We have a requirement in which need to convert XML into Fixed Length File.
First record is as header and after that we have actual records..From 2 record onwards we need to apply the logic which is mentioned below:
1.After length 45, consider 10 numbers 0000001000, what ever be the 
        last digit we need to check and replace by following the below 
         table:

```
      "For Positive Amount: (0000001000)   - (000000100{)             
      {= 0                                          
      A = 1                                       
      B = 2                                      
      c = 3                                      
      D = 4                                     
      E = 5                                      
      F = 6                                     
      G = 7                                      
      H = 8                                     
      I = 9
```

I have not that much idea so created the small XSLT , request anyone please help on the same.

Input:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ZR>
<INPUT>
   <I_FIL>ERES</I_FIL>
  </INPUT>
  <TABLES>
   <T_ER>
    <item>
        <DATA> HEADER1111111122222222333333344456</DATA>
    </item>
    <item>
         <DATA>778944    D4E2   EA     1234567891 2018-11-060000001000EA 
       0000000000000100001020D04YA30TRE0000000XXXYYY 300{  P 2018-11-05</DATA>
    </item>
    <item>
        <DATA>987654    D4E2   EA     1987654321 2018-11-060000002001EA 
       0000000000000100001020D04YA30UUU0000000XXXLRB 100{  P 2018-11-05</DATA>
    </item>
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
</T_ER>
</TABLES>
</ZR>
```

XSLT:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
     <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />

       <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="ZR/TABLES/T_ER/item[1]/DATA"/> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output:

```
     HEADER1111111122222222333333344456
        778944    D4E2   EA     1234567891 2018-11-06000000100{EA 
       0000000000000100001020D04YA30TRE0000000XXXYYY 300{  P 2018-11-05
    987654    D4E2   EA     1987654321 2018-11-06000000200AEA 
       0000000000000100001020D04YA30UUU0000000XXXLRB 100{  P 2018-11-05
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want to replace the 55th character based on your map, so you could do this...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="ZR/TABLES/T_ER/item[1]/DATA"/> 
<xsl:value-of select="$break" />
<xsl:for-each select="ZR/TABLES/T_ER/item[position() > 1]/DATA">
  <xsl:variable name="char" select="substring('{ABCDEFGHI', number(substring(., 55, 1)) + 1, 1)" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1, 54), $char, substring(., 56))" />
  <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This would work in XSLT 1.0.

An XSLT 2.0 solution could be this...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="ZR/TABLES/T_ER/item[1]/DATA,
                      ZR/TABLES/T_ER/item[position() > 1]/DATA/concat(substring(., 1, 54), substring('{ABCDEFGHI', number(substring(., 55, 1)) + 1, 1), substring(., 56))" 
              separator="&#xA;" />
</xsl:template>
```

In XSLT 3.0, you could potentially make use of a `map` with has the advantage of easily being extended if you wanted to consider two or more characters instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" >

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />

  <xsl:variable name="chars" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)">
    <xsl:map>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'0'" select="'{'"/>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'1'" select="'A'"/>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'2'" select="'B'"/>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'3'" select="'C'"/>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'4'" select="'D'"/>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'5'" select="'E'"/>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'6'" select="'F'"/>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'7'" select="'G'"/>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'8'" select="'H'"/>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'9'" select="'I'"/>
    </xsl:map>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="ZR/TABLES/T_ER/item[1]/DATA,
                          ZR/TABLES/T_ER/item[position() > 1]/DATA/concat(substring(., 1, 54), $chars(substring(., 55, 1)), substring(., 56))" separator="&#xA;" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There's probably a much nicer way in XSLT 3.0, so hopefully Martin Honnen will be along soon to say....

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing , works nicely.  :) Three things which I forgot to mention -  1.I have header at the end...2.Same logic we need to repeat at position 59th to 74th..3.Also  77th to 80th  - 1020 we need to store value in variable.Please let me know if I have to post the question again.or Shall I modify ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, using functions `string-length`, `substring` and `translate` for your specifications it can be achieved as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="ZR/TABLES/T_ER/item[1]/DATA" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$break" />

    <xsl:for-each select="ZR/TABLES/T_ER/item[position() != 1]">

        <xsl:variable name="length" select="string-length(substring(DATA,0,46))" />
        <xsl:variable name="tenNumbers" select="substring(DATA, ($length + 1), 10)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="charToReplace" select="translate(substring($tenNumbers, string-length($tenNumbers), 1),'0123456789','{ABCDEFGHI')" />

        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(DATA,0,46), substring(DATA, ($length + 1), 9), $charToReplace, substring(DATA,($length+11),(string-length(DATA) + 1)))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
    </xsl:for-each>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing , works nicely. :) Three things which I forgot to mention - 1.I have header at the end...2.Same logic we need to repeat at position 59th to 74th..3.Also 77th to 80th - 1020 we need to store value in variable.Please let me know if I have to post the question again.or Shall I modify ?

Comment: You can do either of the thing. If it's working fine, close the question by accepting either of the answers and post new one for your queries. Or you can update this too.

Comment: Thanks will raise a new one.